# How do I put linebreaks in tooltips?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, svg

i am using this tutorial to add tooltips to my svg:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

here is a sample of my svg:

```
<path 
       d="M 747.96137,581.40584 L 749.98034,589.3338 L 753.58521,598.75 L 758.74146,607.8125 L 762.33521,613.90625 L 767.02271,619.21875 L 770.92896,622.8125 L 772.49146,625.625 L 771.39771,626.875 L 770.61646,628.125 L 773.42896,635.3125 L 776.24146,638.125 L 778.74146,643.28125 L 782.17896,648.90625 L 786.55396,656.875 L 787.80396,664.21875 L 788.27271,675.78125 L 788.89771,677.5 L 788.58521,680.78125 L 786.24146,682.03125 L 786.55396,683.90625 L 785.92896,685.78125 L 786.24146,688.125 L 786.71021,690 L 784.05396,693.125 L 781.08521,694.53125 L 777.33521,694.6875 L 775.92896,696.25 L 773.58521,697.1875 L 772.33521,696.71875 L 771.24146,695.78125 L 770.92896,692.96875 L 770.14771,689.6875 L 766.86646,684.6875 L 763.42896,682.5 L 759.67896,682.1875 L 758.89771,683.4375 L 755.92896,679.21875 L 755.30396,675.78125 L 752.80396,671.875 L 751.08521,670.78125 L 749.52271,672.8125 L 747.80396,672.5 L 745.77271,667.65625 L 742.96021,663.90625 L 740.14771,658.75 L 737.64771,655.78125 L 734.21021,652.1875 L 736.24146,649.84375 L 739.36646,644.53125 L 739.21021,642.96875 L 734.83521,642.03125 L 733.27271,642.65625 L 733.58521,643.28125 L 736.08521,644.21875 L 734.67896,648.59375 L 733.89771,649.0625 L 732.17896,645.15625 L 730.92896,640.46875 L 730.61646,637.8125 L 732.02271,633.28125 L 732.02271,624.0625 L 729.05396,620.46875 L 727.80396,617.5 L 722.80396,616.25 L 720.92896,615.625 L 719.36646,613.125 L 716.08521,611.5625 L 714.99146,608.28125 L 712.33521,607.34375 L 709.99146,603.75 L 705.92896,602.34375 L 703.11646,600.9375 L 700.61646,600.9375 L 696.71021,601.71875 L 696.55396,603.59375 L 697.33521,604.53125 L 696.86646,605.625 L 693.89771,605.46875 L 690.30396,608.90625 L 686.86646,610.78125 L 683.11646,610.78125 L 679.99146,612.03125 L 679.67896,609.375 L 678.11646,607.5 L 675.30396,606.40625 L 673.74146,605 L 665.92896,601.25 L 658.58521,599.53125 L 654.36646,600.15625 L 648.58521,600.625 L 642.80396,602.65625 L 639.44116,603.2487 L 639.2112,595.46836 L 636.7112,593.59336 L 634.99245,591.87461 L 635.30495,588.90585 L 645.14871,587.65585 L 669.83625,584.84335 L 676.39876,584.21835 L 682.33627,584.06209 L 684.83627,587.8121 L 686.24252,589.21835 L 693.89879,589.3746 L 704.35642,588.7496 L 725.14883,587.4996 L 730.41229,586.8478 L 734.83635,586.8746 L 734.9926,589.6871 L 737.4926,590.46835 L 737.8051,586.2496 L 736.2426,581.87459 L 737.33635,580.31209 L 742.96136,581.09334 L 747.96137,581.40584 z M 759.91605,710.23387 L 762.25981,709.60887 L 763.50981,709.3745 L 764.91607,707.10886 L 767.1817,705.54636 L 768.43171,706.01511 L 770.07234,706.32761 L 770.46296,707.34324 L 767.10358,708.51512 L 763.04106,709.92137 L 760.77543,711.09325 L 759.91605,710.23387 z M 772.96297,705.39011 L 774.13485,706.40574 L 776.79111,704.37448 L 781.94738,700.31197 L 785.54114,696.56195 L 787.96302,690.15568 L 788.90053,688.51505 L 789.05678,685.23379 L 788.35365,685.70254 L 787.41615,688.43692 L 786.00989,692.89006 L 782.88488,697.96821 L 778.66612,702.03072 L 775.38486,703.90573 L 772.96297,705.39011 z"
       id="FL" 
       style="fill:#f2d0ff" /> 

    <path 
       d="M 753.42896,550.78125 L 751.71137,551.7183 L 749.21137,550.46829 L 748.58637,548.43704 L 747.33637,544.99954 L 745.14886,542.96828 L 742.64886,542.34328 L 741.08636,537.65578 L 738.4301,531.87452 L 734.3676,529.99951 L 732.33634,528.12451 L 731.08634,525.62451 L 729.05509,523.7495 L 726.86759,522.4995 L 724.68008,519.687 L 721.71133,517.4995 L 717.33632,515.78074 L 716.86757,514.37449 L 714.52382,511.56199 L 714.05507,510.15573 L 710.77381,505.15573 L 707.49256,505.31198 L 703.5863,502.96822 L 702.3363,501.71822 L 702.0238,499.99947 L 702.80505,498.12447 L 704.99255,497.18696 L 704.68005,495.15571 L 710.61756,492.65571 L 719.36757,488.2807 L 726.39883,487.49945 L 742.33636,487.0307 L 744.52386,488.9057 L 746.08636,492.03071 L 750.30512,491.56196 L 762.49264,490.1557 L 765.30514,490.93696 L 777.49266,498.28072 L 787.26244,506.13059 L 782.02271,511.40625 L 779.52271,517.34375 L 779.05396,523.4375 L 777.49146,524.21875 L 776.39771,526.875 L 774.05396,527.5 L 772.02271,530.9375 L 769.36646,533.59375 L 767.17896,536.875 L 765.61646,537.65625 L 762.17896,540.9375 L 759.36646,541.09375 L 760.30396,544.21875 L 755.46021,549.53125 L 753.42896,550.78125 z"
       id="SC"
       style="fill:#ffd0d0" /> 
    <path 
       d="M 684.21127,497.65572 L 679.52376,498.43697 L 671.39875,499.53072 L 663.11749,500.39009 L 663.11749,502.49947 L 663.27374,504.53073 L 663.89874,507.81198 L 667.18,515.46824 L 669.52375,524.99951 L 670.93,530.93702 L 672.4925,535.62452 L 673.89876,542.34328 L 675.93001,548.43704 L 678.43001,551.7183 L 678.89876,554.99955 L 680.77377,555.7808 L 680.93002,557.81206 L 679.21126,562.49956 L 678.74251,565.62457 L 678.58626,567.49957 L 680.14877,571.71833 L 680.46127,576.87458 L 679.68001,579.21834 L 680.30502,579.99959 L 681.71127,580.78084 L 682.33627,584.06209 L 684.83627,587.8121 L 686.24252,589.21835 L 693.89879,589.3746 L 704.35642,588.7496 L 725.14883,587.4996 L 730.41229,586.8478 L 734.83635,586.8746 L 734.9926,589.6871 L 737.4926,590.46835 L 737.8051,586.2496 L 736.2426,581.87459 L 737.33635,580.31209 L 742.96136,581.09334 L 747.77218,581.40049 L 747.02271,575.3125 L 749.21021,565.625 L 750.61646,561.5625 L 750.14771,559.0625 L 754.05396,552.34375 L 753.47531,550.78102 L 751.71137,551.7183 L 749.21137,550.46829 L 748.58637,548.43704 L 747.33637,544.99954 L 745.14886,542.96828 L 742.64886,542.34328 L 741.08636,537.65578 L 738.4301,531.87452 L 734.3676,529.99951 L 732.33634,528.12451 L 731.08634,525.62451 L 729.05509,523.7495 L 726.86759,522.4995 L 724.68008,519.687 L 721.71133,517.4995 L 717.33632,515.78074 L 716.86757,514.37449 L 714.52382,511.56199 L 714.05507,510.15573 L 710.77381,505.15573 L 707.49256,505.31198 L 703.5863,502.96822 L 702.3363,501.71822 L 702.0238,499.99947 L 702.80505,498.12447 L 704.99255,497.18696 L 704.8363,494.98049 L 703.11755,495.46821 L 697.49254,496.40571 L 690.77378,497.18696 L 684.21127,497.65572 z"
       id="GA"
       style="fill:#d7ffd0" />
```

here is the index.html that includes everything:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JavaScript Tooltip Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<embed src="usmap.svg" width="3000" height="1000"
type="image/svg+xml"
pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".addtooltip").tooltip();
    }); // closes document.ready
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is how i edited the SVG:

```
<path 
   d="M 170.46112,590.15502 L 170.14862,672.65541 L 171.71112,673.59291 L 174.67989,673.74916 L 176.08614,672.65541 L 178.58615,672.65541 L 178.74241,675.46792 L 185.46119,682.03045 L 185.92994,684.53046 L 189.2112,682.65545 L 189.83621,682.4992 L 190.14871,679.53044 L 191.55496,677.96793 L 192.64872,677.81168 L 194.52373,676.40542 L 197.49249,678.43668 L 198.1175,681.2492 L 199.9925,682.34295 L 201.08626,684.68671 L 204.83628,686.40547 L 208.11754,692.18675 L 210.7738,695.93676 L 212.96131,698.59303 L 214.36757,702.18679 L 219.21134,703.90555 L 224.21137,705.93681 L 225.14887,710.15558 L 225.61762,713.12434 L 224.68012,716.40561 L 222.96136,718.59312 L 221.39885,717.81187 L 219.9926,714.8431 L 217.33633,713.43685 L 215.61758,712.34309 L 214.83632,713.12434 L 216.24258,715.78061 L 216.39883,719.37437 L 215.30507,719.84312 L 213.43007,717.96812 L 211.39881,716.71811 L 211.86756,718.28062 L 213.11756,719.99938 L 212.33631,720.78063 C 212.33631,720.78063 211.55506,720.46813 211.08631,719.84312 C 210.61755,719.21812 209.05505,716.56186 209.05505,716.56186 L 208.11754,714.37435 C 208.11754,714.37435 207.80504,715.62436 207.18004,715.31185 C 206.55503,714.99935 205.93003,713.9056 205.93003,713.9056 L 207.64879,712.03059 L 206.24253,710.62433 L 206.24253,705.78056 L 205.46128,705.78056 L 204.68003,709.06182 L 203.58627,709.53058 L 202.64877,705.93681 L 202.02376,702.34304 L 201.24251,701.87429 L 201.55501,707.34307 L 201.55501,708.43682 L 200.14875,707.18682 L 196.71124,701.40554 L 194.67998,700.93679 L 194.05498,697.34302 L 192.49247,694.53051 L 190.92996,693.43675 L 190.92996,691.24924 L 192.96122,689.99924 L 192.49247,689.68674 L 189.99246,690.31174 L 186.71119,687.96798 L 184.21118,685.15546 L 179.52366,682.65545 L 175.61739,680.15544 L 176.8674,677.03043 L 176.8674,675.46792 L 175.14864,677.03043 L 172.33613,678.12418 L 168.74236,677.03043 L 163.27358,674.68667 L 157.96106,674.68667 L 157.33606,675.15542 L 151.08603,671.4054 L 149.05477,671.0929 L 146.39851,665.46787 L 142.96099,665.78037 L 139.52347,667.18663 L 139.99223,671.56165 L 141.08598,668.74914 L 142.02349,669.06164 L 140.61723,673.28041 L 143.74224,670.62415 L 144.36725,672.18665 L 140.61723,676.40542 L 139.36722,676.09292 L 138.89847,674.21791 L 137.64847,673.43666 L 136.39846,674.53042 L 133.7422,672.81166 L 130.77343,674.84292 L 129.05468,676.87418 L 125.77341,678.90544 L 121.24214,678.74918 L 120.77339,676.71793 L 124.36715,676.09292 L 124.36715,674.84292 L 122.17964,674.21791 L 123.11715,671.87415 L 125.30466,668.12414 L 125.30466,666.40538 L 125.46091,665.62412 L 129.67968,663.43661 L 130.61718,664.68662 L 133.27345,664.68662 L 132.02344,662.18661 L 128.42967,661.87411 L 123.5859,664.53037 L 121.24214,667.81163 L 119.52338,670.31165 L 118.42963,672.49916 L 114.36711,673.90541 L 111.39834,676.40542 L 111.08584,677.96793 L 113.27335,678.90544 L 114.05461,680.93669 L 111.39834,684.06171 L 105.14832,688.12423 L 97.648277,692.18675 L 95.617017,693.2805 L 90.460745,694.37426 L 85.304465,696.56177 L 87.023225,697.81177 L 85.616965,699.21803 L 85.148215,700.31178 L 82.491955,699.37428 L 79.366945,699.53053 L 78.585685,701.71804 L 77.648185,701.71804 L 77.960685,699.37428 L 74.523165,700.62429 L 71.710655,701.56179 L 68.42939,700.31178 L 65.616877,702.18679 L 62.491863,702.18679 L 60.460603,703.4368 L 58.898096,704.21805 L 56.866837,703.90555 L 54.366825,702.8118 L 52.179315,703.4368 L 51.241811,704.3743 L 49.679303,703.28055 L 49.679303,701.40554 L 52.648067,700.15553 L 58.741845,700.78054 L 62.960615,699.21803 L 64.991874,697.18677 L 67.804387,696.56177 L 69.523145,695.78051 L 72.179408,695.93676 L 73.741915,697.18677 L 74.679415,696.87427 L 76.866925,694.21801 L 79.835695,693.2805 L 83.116955,692.6555 L 84.366965,692.343 L 84.991965,692.81175 L 85.773225,692.81175 L 87.023225,689.21798 L 90.929495,687.81173 L 92.804505,684.21796 L 94.992017,679.84294 L 96.554527,678.43668 L 96.867027,675.93667 L 95.304517,677.18668 L 92.023245,677.81168 L 91.398245,675.46792 L 90.148245,675.15542 L 89.210735,676.09292 L 89.054485,678.90544 L 87.648225,678.74918 L 86.241975,673.12416 L 84.991965,674.37416 L 83.898215,673.90541 L 83.585715,672.0304 L 79.679445,672.18665 L 77.648185,673.28041 L 75.148175,672.96791 L 76.554425,671.56165 L 77.023175,669.06164 L 76.398175,667.18663 L 77.804435,666.24913 L 79.054435,666.09288 L 78.429435,664.37412 L 78.429435,660.15535 L 77.491935,659.21784 L 76.710675,660.6241 L 70.773151,660.6241 L 69.366895,659.37409 L 68.741892,655.62408 L 66.710632,652.18656 L 66.710632,651.24906 L 68.741892,650.4678 L 68.898142,648.43654 L 69.991897,647.34279 L 69.210644,646.87404 L 67.960638,647.34279 L 66.866883,644.68653 L 67.804387,639.84275 L 72.179408,636.71774 L 74.679415,635.15523 L 76.554425,631.56147 L 79.210695,630.31146 L 81.710705,631.40522 L 82.023205,633.74898 L 84.366965,633.43647 L 87.491975,631.09271 L 89.054485,631.71772 L 89.991985,632.34272 L 91.554495,632.34272 L 93.742007,631.09271 L 94.523267,626.87394 C 94.523267,626.87394 94.835767,624.06143 95.460767,623.59268 C 96.085767,623.12393 96.398267,622.65518 96.398267,622.65518 L 95.304517,620.78017 L 92.804505,621.56142 L 89.679485,622.34267 L 87.804475,621.87392 L 84.366965,620.15516 L 79.523195,619.99891 L 76.085675,616.40515 L 76.554425,612.65513 L 77.179435,610.31137 L 75.148175,608.59261 L 73.273163,604.99884 L 73.741915,604.21759 L 80.304445,603.74884 L 82.335705,603.74884 L 83.273205,604.68634 L 83.898215,604.68634 L 83.741965,603.12383 L 87.491975,602.49883 L 89.991985,602.81133 L 91.398245,603.90509 L 89.991985,605.93635 L 89.523235,607.3426 L 92.179505,608.90511 L 97.023277,610.62387 L 98.742037,609.68637 L 96.554527,605.4676 L 95.617017,602.34258 L 96.554527,601.56133 L 93.273257,599.68632 L 92.804505,598.59256 L 93.273257,597.03006 L 92.492005,593.28004 L 89.679485,588.74877 L 87.335725,584.68625 L 90.148245,582.81124 L 93.273257,582.81124 L 94.992017,583.43624 L 99.054537,583.27999 L 102.6483,579.84248 L 103.74206,576.87371 L 107.33583,574.52995 L 108.89833,575.46746 L 111.55459,574.84245 L 115.14836,572.81119 L 116.24212,572.65494 L 117.17962,573.4362 L 121.55464,573.27995 L 124.2109,570.31118 L 125.30466,570.31118 L 128.74217,572.65494 L 130.61718,574.6862 L 130.14843,575.77996 L 130.77343,576.87371 L 132.33594,575.31121 L 136.08596,575.62371 L 136.39846,579.21747 L 138.27347,580.62373 L 145.1485,581.24873 L 151.24228,585.31125 L 152.64853,584.37375 L 157.64856,586.87376 L 159.67982,586.24876 L 161.55483,585.4675 L 166.24235,587.34251 L 170.46112,590.15502 z M 59.210598,618.1239 L 61.241857,623.28018 L 61.085606,624.21768 L 58.273093,623.90518 L 56.554335,619.99891 L 54.835577,618.59266 L 52.491816,618.59266 L 52.335566,616.09264 L 54.054324,613.74888 L 55.148079,616.09264 L 56.554335,617.4989 L 59.210598,618.1239 z M 56.710586,650.4678 L 60.304353,651.24906 L 63.898119,652.18656 L 64.679373,653.12407 L 63.116866,656.71783 L 60.148102,656.56158 L 56.866837,653.12407 L 56.710586,650.4678 z M 36.710493,636.87399 L 37.804249,639.374 L 38.898004,640.93651 L 37.804249,641.71776 L 35.772989,638.749 L 35.772989,636.87399 L 36.710493,636.87399 z M 23.429182,707.49932 L 26.710447,705.31181 L 29.991712,704.3743 L 32.491724,704.6868 L 32.960476,706.24931 L 34.835485,706.71806 L 36.710493,704.84306 L 36.397992,703.28055 L 39.054254,702.65555 L 41.866767,705.15556 L 40.773012,706.87431 L 36.554243,707.96807 L 33.89798,707.49932 L 30.304214,706.40556 L 26.085444,707.81182 L 24.522937,708.12432 L 23.429182,707.49932 z M 70.773151,703.1243 L 72.335658,704.99931 L 74.366915,703.4368 L 72.960661,702.18679 L 70.773151,703.1243 z M 73.585664,706.09306 L 74.679415,703.90555 L 76.710675,704.21805 L 75.929425,706.09306 L 73.585664,706.09306 z M 96.398267,704.21805 L 97.804527,705.93681 L 98.742037,704.84306 L 97.960777,702.96805 L 96.398267,704.21805 z M 104.83581,692.18675 L 105.92957,697.81177 L 108.74208,698.59303 L 113.58585,695.78051 L 117.80462,693.2805 L 116.24212,690.93674 L 116.71087,688.59298 L 114.67961,689.84299 L 111.8671,689.06173 L 113.4296,687.96798 L 115.30461,688.74923 L 119.05463,687.03047 L 119.52338,685.62422 L 117.17962,684.84296 L 117.96087,682.96795 L 115.30461,684.84296 L 110.77334,688.28048 L 106.08582,691.09299 L 104.83581,692.18675 z M 145.7735,672.96791 L 148.11726,671.56165 L 147.17976,669.84289 L 145.461,670.7804 L 145.7735,672.96791 z"
   id="AK"
       class="addtooltip"
       onmousemove="GetTrueCoords(evt);"
   style="fill:#f2d0ff"
       title="this sis akw<br>ith a line break" >
    </path>
```

it is not working correctly

what am i doing wrong?