# is it possible to insert a line break in this tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, tooltip

i have a pretty map of the US:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg

i would like to implement a tooltip with multiline functionality such as here over the red square:

http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/gui/tooltips/

please help me get started on this. i will be offering a maximum bounty on this.

Comment: For what purpose? The title is shown in the browser title bar, and won't show a line break.

Comment: And how do you envision that displayed in the title bar of the browser?

Comment: this question don't make any sense. Why do you want a line break there? is it after the first 3 words or just random? try explaining your question better.

Comment: thank you very much, ive updated my question. please let me know if i can clarify anything

Comment: question makes no sense. in your example there are no line breaks. And then you talk about tooltips... so is your question really, "how do i put line breaks in tool tips?"

Comment: having multiple title tags is just strange.  the HTML Title tag is used to display the page title in the browsers title bar... not to be spread all willy-nilly throughout your markup.

Comment: absolutely **DO NOT USE** `<title></title>` the way you're using it above. It's totally wrong. instead use `<[element] title="" />`

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568826/how-do-i-put-linebreaks-in-tooltips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never cease to amaze me, I__!  How many projects are you working on?

Tooltips are browser-generated quick popups; you should use `\n` to set the `.title` attribute in JavaScript.

Comment: they keep throwing me around. i dont even have education in programming. one day im doing SQL the next day SVG. but i get a lot of whining from soverflow for asking too many questions

Comment: the problem is that people here are speaking with me as if i am a well seasoned javascript programmer. I DONT KNOW ANYTHING ABOUT JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Different browsers handle line breaks inside title attributes differently — some render line breaks, some treat them as generic white space, some displaying the unprintable character character. They should be avoided.

Comment: It appears that Firefox 14, IE 9, and Chrome 21 all treat \n as a newline in the title tooltip.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use some [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) magic and use the title **"Attribute"** instead of a Title **"Tag"**?
*I think you're confusing the two in your original question*

Check out this jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/s5qUw/2/

I've also used the [jQuery Tools Tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html)

**Markup** *note: Basically all YOU need to do is add the `title` attribute and the `addtooltip` class to any page element that you want to add a tooltip to.  Then you can use CSS to style the tooltip however you see fit.*

```
<path
   id="AK"
   class="addtooltip"
   style="fill:#f2d0ff" 
   onmousemove="GetTrueCoords(evt);"
   title="this sis ak<br>with a line break">
</path>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {
    display:none;
    background-color:black;
    font-size:12px;
    height:40px;
    width:160px;
    padding:25px;
    color:#fff;    
}
```

**Script** (bottom of your page)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.4/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".addtooltip").tooltip();
    }); // closes document.ready
</script>
```

Comment: the bottom line is that you're using the `TITLE` tag all wrong.  DONT USE IT THAT WAY.  You can however use the `title` attribute on all of your page elements.  Take a look at my slightly edited answer.

Comment: i really appreciate your time, but i cannot change the entire code to do it your way. can you please suggest to me how i can make slight changes in the way i am doing things to solve my issue?

Comment: and no, I can't suggest (in my own good conscience) a way for you to make slight changes in the way you're doing it.  Cus you're doing it all wrong. The `Title` tag is not to be used that way... ever.

Comment: thank you very much i will try it right now, what do i have to download and can u tell me what i have to include with jquery to make this work. i have not used jquery before

Comment: look at the JSFiddle example in the answer.  It's just using the jQuery library and the jQuery Tools library (which I have linked to in the answer as well).

Comment: thank you. i have done this but it is not working. where should this line go: $(".addtooltip").tooltip();?

Comment: **1)** you're missing the jquery library `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`... **2)** you should put all of your script elements at the **bottom** of the page.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean. i am putting all the scripts at the bottom of the index.html page. please check edits

Comment: here's an example on how to add javascript to your SVG - http://apike.ca/prog_svg_jsanim.html

Comment: yes but i have the javascript in index.html file not in svg. should i put the function in the svg file instead?

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

The title of the page is handed off to the browser and not rendered in the page; usually that means it shows up in the application's [title bar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_bar). Actually rendering a newline would make the title bar twice as tall (or more, with multiple newlines) - and that's not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is a known problem and you have to handle it like this:

```
<desc>
   <tspan x="10" y="10">An orange</tspan>
   <tspan x="10" y="24.5">circle</tspan>
</desc>
```

Comment: but i feel like you are definitely on to something

Comment: i imagine you have to consider what the proper x/y should be for your application. You could be potentially positioning it off screen or at least somewhere invisible. Mess with the x/y? Not sure if they're relative to the element they are in or to the whole document.

Comment: can you show me the source of where you found this known problem

Comment: 'tspan' elements need a "text content block element" parent to show anything, see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/intro.html#TermTextContentBlockElement (for SVG 1.1 the only such element is 'text'). Although inside a 'desc' element it's not going to do much anyway, unless the script pulls it out and tries to display it somehow.

Comment: @Erik Dahlström: thank you very much for your response. can you tell me what should i do?

Comment: If you want to use the script you have above, then you'll need to modify the script to handle multiline, since it doesn't seem to be supported. Or you could switch to another solution. You might be able to find a working solution from http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/gui/tooltips/ which shows multiline svg tooltips.

Comment: Here's where i found the original response: http://support.adobe.com/devsup/devsup.nsf/docs/50547.htm

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by  creating the tooltip value with `<br/>` from my server side.

Answer (score 0):

A line break in html is `<br />`. You can add that anywhere you like.

FYI - there is no tag named 'field1', so your getElementsByTagName call will find nothing.

Comment: thank you very much, ive updated my question. please let me know if i can clarify anything

Comment: You can easily replace commas with <br /> tags using the replace function (as partick dw suggested). But, I am still a little confused. You are using getElementsByTagName to look for 'desc' tags - there are no such tags in valid html, and this search will fail.

Comment: as per recommendation below the question then must be HOW DO I PUT LINE BREAKS IN TOOLTIPS?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<br/>` where you want the break.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this depends on where do you want that Line Break to show...
If it should be seen on the page you should add a `<br />`, if you need that to show only on the page code, you should add a `\n`.
if you want to do the thing you've asked you simply need to replace in your code the `,` in `<br />` if this text will be shown in an HTML ToolTip. If this will be shown in a Javascript Alert you should use `\n`.

Comment: thank you very much, ive updated my question. please let me know if i can clarify anything

Answer (score 0):

The mouseover an SVG element, with a  `<title>` child element is the easiest choice, when it can be **shortened**. Both FF/Chrome will extend it in a single line. IE will automatically limit it to about 50 characters. The following will take a looooong tooltip and break its line, inserting line breaks(\n) at the desired location between words. The String.prototpye function can be applied before/after filling the `<title>` text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>SVG ToolTip line breaks</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
Three Elements Contained in a &lt;g>, plus a &lt;title> element,<br /> used as its tooltip.<br />
<svg width=400 height=400>
<g>
<circle cx=150 cy=150 r=60 fill=red />
<rect x=200 y=200 width=60 height=60 fill=lime />
<ellipse cx=300 cy=300 rx=60 ry=20 fill=blue />
<title id=myToolTip>This is a tool tip for this symbol (a group of elements), that will help describe what it is</title>
</g></svg>
<br /><button onClick=wrapToolTip(25)>wrap tooltip</button>
</center>
</body>
<script>
/* --- Adds SVG line break at space between words when it would exceed the max length
(or if a single loooong word exceeds the Max Line length)
Also usable for HTML line break by including true arg---
*/
String.prototype.fullWrap= function(maxLineLength,htm){
    var str1, tem, ax, diff, lim, S= [], br;
    var A= this.split(/\\s*\//);

    while(A.length){
        str1= A.shift();
        while(str1 && str1.length> maxLineLength){
            if(ax=== 0 && /^\\S/.test(str1)) S[S.length-1]+= '-';
            tem= str1.substring(0, maxLineLength);
            ax= tem.lastIndexOf(' ')+ 1;
            if(ax== 0){
                S.push(str1.substring(0, maxLineLength-1));
                str1= str1.substring(maxLineLength-1);
            }
            else{
                tem= str1.substring(0, ax);
                str1= str1.substring(ax);
                S.push(tem);
            }
        }
        if(str1) S.push(str1);
    }
    if(htm)
        br="<br/>" //--html--
    else
        br="\n"  //----text line break
    return S.join(br);
}

function wrapToolTip(maxLen)
{
   myToolTip.firstChild.data=myToolTip.firstChild.data.fullWrap(maxLen)
}
</script>
</html>
```