# EDGE issue - add new line in tooltip for title attribute in dc.js chart

Tags: javascript, html, svg, microsoft-edge, dc.js

> This issue is only for EDGE browser

So far, for our [dc.js](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) chart - we have tried [9 different approaches for showing title attribute value in new line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39658112/2404470)

Now, when I try to implement them with my chart:

```
.renderTitle(true)
.title(function (p) {
    return [
          'ABC',
          'DEF',
          'GHI',
          'JKL']
          .join('\n');
})
```

Where `\n` is replaced with

- `\x0A`
- `&#013;`
- `\t`
- `&#xD;`
- `&#10;`

They [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/mrya78a8/) for HTML.

I was doubtful that they're working only with HTML, so I tried [SVG only fix as suggested by @joews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29781899/2404470)

```
.renderTitle(true)
.title(function (p) {

    return [
          '<tspan>ABC',
          '</tspan><tspan>DEF',
          '</tspan><tspan>GHI',
          '</tspan><tspan>JKL'</tspan>']
          .join('');
})
```

And the style rule is also applied:

```
tspan:nth-child(2n) {
  display: block;
}
```

Have also tried pure d3.js approach

```
.append("svg:title")
.append("tspan")
.text('ABC'+'\nDEF'+'\nGHI'+'\nJKL')
```

None of these are working to bring new line in tooltips.

**What is the fix?**

Comment: As I understand it, the question is purely about the behavior of `title` tags on Microsoft Edge. I've edited the tags to suit.

Comment: Googling for "svg title element newline" brings up quite a few old questions - looks like browser behavior has been inconsistent for a long time. Maybe use d3-tip instead?

Comment: @Gordon I've tried the top 3 solutions: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3578406/2404470), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29781899/2404470) & [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/358903/2404470). None of them have worked for us. Also d3-tip is not an option for now atleast

Comment: Right, it looks like there is no consistent support for what you're trying to do. IMO if you have formatting needs it's always better to use d3-tip.

Answer (score 0):

Tries to put the tag 'br' where you want to break.

```
<p title="Tool&#13;Tip&#13;On&#13;New&#13;Line">Tooltip with <br /> works Firefox browsers</p>
```

---

https://jsfiddle.net/aneukirchen/mrya78a8/17/

Comment: The problem is for `title` attribute

Comment: document.getElementById("tooltip").setAttribute("title", "Tool '<br />' New Line")

Comment: The problem is for `title` attribute for an `svg` element not for `html`

Comment: Actually in this case it is more complicated!

Comment: And that's my problem